# How does Lacto effect apperance?

Tags: yeast, lactobacillus

Reading a [Wikipedia article on Lacto yogurt cultures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactobacillus_delbrueckii_subsp._bulgaricus) I notice a reference to beer. In a general statement they claim *"lactic acid bacteria can contribute to the overall appearance, aroma, taste, and/or mouthfeel"...* I'm familiar the lacto aroma and taste, but never considered the effects on appearance. Is this true, and if so, in what way, or is it just misinformation on the internet?

Comment: I would assume lacto will make a beer clearer, like Brett, although I can't say WHY I assume this.

Comment: Are we talking about beer or yogurt?  I think that I have seen that lacto does not flocc well so it tends to contribute to a hazy finish in beer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lactobacillus delbrueckii does very little to effect the appearance of your beer.  In terms of flocculation (dropping out of suspension in the beer, leaving a clear appearance), I would compare it to a medium/high flocculation Saccharomyces Cerevisiae strain.  With proper aging and use of fining agents if desired, it will not impart a significant haze on your beer.

The common reason for the perception that lacto imparts a haze is because it is often used in part, or as a blend with other low flocculating microbes such as the various strains of Brettanomyces (to help fight off the production of diacetyl which Brett chews right through), which is low in flocculation and can very easily leave a very cloudy beer.  In fact, the cloudiest beer I ever produced came from fermenting a farmhouse style with a blend of WLP653 (Brettanomyces lambicus) and (WLP644 Brettanomyces bruxellensis Trois).  I didn't cold crash it, and when pouring, it was as thick in appearance as a fruit juice with off-putting levels of yeast settling to the bottom of each glass poured, but I digress.

As long as you ferment along with another yeast strain (wild or otherwise), the addition of Lactobacillus in your fermentation will not effect the appearance to any measurable degree.